# Could we influence an entangled particle through environmental changes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

If we had an quantum entangled particle pair separated by an arbitrary distance. If we then subjected one particle of the pair to an environmental change e.g. Reduce temperature to close to absolute 0k, very high magnetic field etc, if we then measured a property of the affected particle could we have influenced the state of the entire entangled system? Would decoherence of the system occur in a way that could indicate, when measuring the particle, that some arbitrary environmental affect had been imposed?

Comment: "temperature" means nothing when you're talking about one particle. But yes, by measuring a property of one particle you affect the other, that's the whole concept of entanglement.

Comment: That is not my question - could we in some way influence what is measured through the environmental conditions. E.g. If we measure the angular momentum operator could that be influenced through a significant magnetic field in a way that would be derteministic?

Comment: How do you think we'd measure spin in the first place? (hint: it uses a significant magnetic field)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is : Yes you would definitely influence your system. But environment in your case only does one thing on a quantum system: it destroys its coherence, therefore making you lose your intrication. from the point of view of the system, this is exactly the same as being subjected to a measurement.

Comment: Thanks David - I understand that (I think) - I suppose my question is when the coherence is destroyed because of the environmental factors could this in someway influence what is measured in the particle?  I was looking at that fact we have created longer lasting entanglement now and at room temperatures.  It would be interesting to know if changing the environment suddenly, forcing decoherence  would have a factor in what we measured in the particle affected...

Comment: it would probably affect the measured particle state. But as soon as you lose coherence, you lose intrication, and further measurements (the ones you are performing on purpose for example) have no reason to yield the same result anymore, especially if the environment is very different for either particle

Comment: Your vocabulary is a bit obscure, but I think you are saying that a unitary transformation applied to one particle destroys the entanglement.  If so, then this answer is certainly wrong.

Comment: Try an example:  Let $A$ and $B$ be a basis for the state space of a single particle.  Start with a pair in state $A\otimes B+B\otimes A$.  Let $U$ be the operator that switches $A$ and $B$ and subject the first particle to an enviornmental change by applying the operator $U\otimes 1$.   The new state is exactly as entangled as the old one, and there is no decoherence.   (Of course the idea that you could detect this via measurements on the second particle is bonkers.)

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  My musing was when decoherence does occur, either through environmental changes or through direct measurement, could a subsequent measurement of the second particle in someway infer how or what forced the decoherence?  I am not talking about direct information exchange - but rather, for example, if particle A was subjected to a massive magnetic field and then measured, some quantum value would be slanted towards X. Could that environmental condition be inferred when particle 2 was measured and the slanting of the same quantum value was to Y...  I am not a physicist BTW!

Comment: @mattluckham :  nothing that happens to particle 1 can have any influence on the distribution of outcomes of any measurement on particle 2.

Comment: Ok, I can see I am on to a loser with this one. But... measuring of particle 1 will in turn have some influence on particle 2 - that is after all the paradoxical nature of entanglement. My leap, and I appreciate it is a leap, is that by influencing the measurement in particle 1 we may be able to get some predictability when measuring particle 2... however, I concede that appears impossible...